# getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefine when running karma test using injector

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

So in my one of the Karma test which looking like below, its showing TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefine!

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AlertsComponent } from './alerts.component';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, SimpleChange, SimpleChanges, Renderer2, Injector, INJECTOR } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertStore } from 'store-manager';
import { of, Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';
import { IntlModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-intl';

describe('Alerts Component', () => {
  let alertComponent: AlertsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AlertsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AlertsComponent],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, IntlModule],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [{ provide: AlertStore, useClass: MockAlertStore },Renderer2]
    }).compileComponents()
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AlertsComponent);
    alertComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('Validate Alert Component instance is creating successfully.', () => {
    expect(alertComponent).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Validate deleteAlert method.', fakeAsync(() => {
    let injector: Injector;
    let alertStore = new AlertStore(injector);

    const response = {
      body: {
        notifications: [
          { "an alert" },
        ]
      }
    };

    spyOn(alertStore, 'getAlertForAccount').and.returnValue(
      Observable.create((observer: Observer<{ body: any }>) => {
        observer.next(response);
        return observer;
      })
    );

    spyOn(alertStore, 'deleteAlert').and.returnValue(
      Observable.create((observer: Observer<{ body: any }>) => {
        observer.next(response);
        return observer;
      })
    );

    fixture.detectChanges();
    alertComponent.deleteAlert("64239");
  }));
```

When I run this, I get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
            at <Jasmine>
            at new AlertStore (http://localhost:9876/home//work/components/components/dist/store-manager/fesm2015/store-manager.js:1381:1)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/alerts/alerts.component.spec.ts:377:22)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/home/work/components/components/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:1442:1)
            at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/home/work/components/components/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:365:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/home/work/components/components/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:305:1)
            at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/home/work/components/components/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:364:1)
            at Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/home/work/components/components/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:124:1)
            at runInTestZone (http://localhost:9876/home/work/components/components/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:554:1)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/home/work/components/components/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:569:1)
```

The error is happening at this line

```
  let alertStore = new AlertStore(injector);
```

here is what alertstore look likes

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfigStore } from './config.store';
import { LoggingService } from 'utils';
import { HttpLibraryService, ResponseType } from '../services/http-library.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AlertStore extends ConfigStore {
    public readonly ALERT_KEY = "alertDetails";

    private _apiURL: string = null;

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        super(injector.get(LoggingService), injector.get(HttpLibraryService));
    }
```

Comment: What is AlertStore? if it a class then may that class constructor throw this error.

Comment: added alert store code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of `AlertStore` expects that it will be injected with an instance of an `Injector` by Angular. In order to do that, Angular needs to create and be aware of the instance of `AlertStore`. You are instead creating your own instance using the `new` keyword, passing in the unitialised field `injector`.

I see you also provide a `MockAlertStore` in your test config. I'm guessing this is what you realy want to be using in your tests. To retrieve the `MockAlertStore` from the test config use:

```
const alertStore = TestBed.get(AlertStore);
```

It will get the instance of `MockAlertStore` created by Angulars `TestBed` to be injected instead of the actual `AlertStore` (see: `providers: [{ provide: AlertStore, useClass: MockAlertStore },...]`). The `MockAlertStore` class may not need the dependency, but this way you will also be spying on the instance that angular injects into the tested component.

Angular documentation has a great section on [dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) that is being used here.

Comment: When I am doing it like you said, it gives me below error

Error: <spyOn> : deleteAlert() method does not exist
        Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>) 

but deleteAlert do exist in alertstore !

Comment: Then you need to add a `deleteAlert` method to the `MockAlertStore` class. It may be completely empty and not return anything - you will replace it with a spy.

Comment: @TalkisCheapShowmeCode For this scenario use jasmin.createObj() instead of creating mock class